# Java: import only needed classes from library project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

is it possible in eclipse to import only needed classes from a project to another? for example I have a project with many file filter and I want to use one of this in another project, my goal is to avoid to generate a jar with unused classes.
are maven or ant useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have experience with it but [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) seems to be something you should have a look into. It detects unused classes, fields, methods and attributes.

btw: It is recommended by the Google Guava guys when you just want to include only the needed parts of Guava.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is doing what you want to achieve. It brings needed jars to your local repository and keep them there until you package your project. Also it doesn't take unused jars. I recommend to use maven.